Hello I am new and trying to learn to code, Issue with GitHub push and pull thing
I am very unfamiliar with Github and wanted to just upload a file I was going to change the next day. I understand this is the repository file is what it's called.
I wanted to have when I do something in VS code to that same project it will update or request an update to go through.
So I tried testing this and I have just ran into issues.
Sorry if this is very nooby I watched a video and thought 5 mins this will be done then I can get back to adding my own things to the project.
I am trying to update something in the main branch and it will not let me and I have no understanding of what issues are going on in the output as it is foreign to me.
Please can I get some guidance on the issue?
The code so far:

git pull --tags
There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to merge with.
See git-pull(1) for details.

git pull <remote> <branch>

If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:
git branch --set-upstream-to=<remote>/<branch> main

I do not know how to even link them together to do push and pulls and have tried some git commands in the terminal and still nothing, it worked when I made a new branch but it did one file and not the one in the "main" folder branch
Error code 1
I just want to be able to update the main branch whenever I wanna add a new feature.
Also just tried git push -f orgin master and this shows
Error code after force push

You should clarify the question and provide more step-by-step information on what you have tried, to help with the debugging e.g how did you create your repository on GitHub remote, did you clone the repo to your local machine, what commands have you run and what errors were you getting, etc

I have not cloned it.
How  I think I made some sort of repository  on VScode was by click "view" on the top left,  then going to the "Command Palette" then typing in "Git: Add Remote" then it let me pick from github which was "miniRPG" and I got the link to the repository and then I thought I was done. That's when it started


Create repository in github website. This is your remote copy
Clone repository to your local machine.
Open VS code in the directory of the repository.
Create files, modify files.
Commit changes in VS code UI.
Push changes to remote.
Pull or clone changes to other machine if necessary.


I feel like an idiot, I fixed it using your directions.
As I went to try make a new file I see the in the new window and has the "Welcome" tab with the new files and other options, it shows right there "Clone Git Repository" I clicked on that and it allowed me to chose the one I was looking for.
I don't know what the videos were telling me and it was that simple.
I appreciate your help and sorry for such a silly question lol.

Glad to now it helped.
